# Show Wordpress posts before today

Tags: wordpress

I try to show posts before today in DESC order in Wordpress.
I got this:

```
<?php query_posts( array( 'cat' => '2186', 'paged' => get_query_var('paged'), 'order' => 'DESC', 'before'  => 'strtotime("now")' ) ); ?>
```

I know I should use the *before* parameter if I refer to the Wordpress documentation.
Actually, this code doesn't work. What should I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, works, and it's easy to modify:

```
$args = array (
   'cat' => '2186',
   'paged' => get_query_var('paged'), 
   'order' => 'DESC', 
   'paged' => $paged, 
   'date_query' => array(
     array(
       'before'    => array(
         'year'  => date('Y'),
         'month' => date('m'),
         'day'   => date('d')
        ),
       'inclusive' => true,
     ),
    ),
);
query_posts($args);
```